# Why $\omega$ can't be bijectively mapped to $\omega +1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\omega$ be the order type of the totally ordered set $\mathbb{N}$, and $\omega +1$ the set $\Bbb{N}\cup \{0\}$.

$0$ is greater than all the natural numbers as per this ordering.

My question is why can't $\Bbb{N}$ be bijectively mapped to $\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$? I understand the basic argument:

1. There is no element in $\Bbb{N}$ which maps to $\{0\}$.
2. $\Bbb{N}$ is bijectively mapped to a proper subset of $\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. A set can't be bijectively mapped to a proper subset of the co-domain and also the co-domain.

But I'm not confident about whether these arguments work for infinite sets. One of the reasons being I used to think if a set can be bijectively mapped to another set, then any permutation of that set can be bijectively mapped to the same set. But this is not true for mapping $\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ to $\Bbb{N}$. Hence I'm not quite sure what arguments are valid for infinite sets.  **My questions:**

**1. Do my arguments work for infinite sets? If not, what arguments are required to prove that $\omega$ can't be bijectively mapped to $\omega + 1$?**

**2. Is picking out every element from the co-domain and proving that it has been injectively mapped to the only way of proving bijection? Does the selection of such an element assume the axiom of choice?**

I realise my question may be unclear, and will attempt to make it more clear should anyone find it difficult to navigate this mess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's common to define $\omega+1$ as $\omega\cup\{\omega\}$. Since $0$ is a natural number in the context of set theory, you should probably write $\Bbb N\cup\{\Bbb N\}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

But $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ **are** equipotent, which is to say: there is a bijection between the two sets. Consider the map $f(n)=n+1, f(\omega)=0$.

There is just no order isomorphism between the two sets. Because order isomorphism preserves the properties of the order, in particular the existence of a maximal element. $\omega+1$ has a maximal element, whereas $\omega$ doesn't.

But more can be said: If two ordinals are order-isomorphic then they are equal.

---

Note that when working with sets which are well-ordered, the axiom of choice is not used. We have a definable choice function (definable from the well-order, that is). In particular, if the codomain is countable we can always make choices.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant a 'similarity mapping' as described in a book. $f(a)\geq f(b)$ iff $a\geq b$. I suppose that is what is meant by order isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry I'd like to add a small question with respect to your answer. You said $f(\omega)=0$. Can we do that? Is that different from saying $f(\infty)=0$ because this is a specific infinite number out of many possible infinitely huge numbers like $\omega^2$ etc? Thanks.

Comment: You should review your basics again. What is $\infty$? $\omega$ is an element in the set $\omega+1$. If we want to define a bijection we need to say where does it go. $\infty$ is not a well-defined set (at least not without context). Is it in the domain of $\omega+1$? Is it something else? Why should $f$ be defined on $\infty$?

Comment: Note that there are bijections between $\omega$ and any countable ordinal, and there are countable ordinals that you can't even begin to imagine. None of these bijections is order preserving, except for the identity function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With regard to my argument: set $A$ can't be order isomorphic with both set $B$ and a proper subset of set $B$; is this argument also valid for infinite sets?

Comment: @Ayush: Certainly not. First note that $\Bbb Q$ is order isomorphic to $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$ which is a proper subset. Also, $\Bbb Z$ is order isomorphic to $\{2k\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$ which is a proper subset, and lastly $\Bbb N$ is order isomorphic to $\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k>42\}$, which is also a proper subset.

Comment: In fact, an infinite cardinal (such as $\omega,\omega_1$) is order isomorphic to any subset of itself with the same cardinality. That said, @AsafKaragila: how absolute is wellorder type (as in: the *ordinal* representing the order type)?

Comment: @tomasz: It is very absolute. The problem is that sometimes when passing down to an inner model (or worse) you lose part of your poset and you end up with something of order type much smaller. For example, Add $\omega_2$ Cohen reals to $L$, now consider the order type of the real numbers. It's $\omega_2$, but when going to $L$ you lose all the Cohen reals and you end up with only $\omega_1$ real numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I see. That's what I thought, thanks. :)